# Adding native library to java project results with unsatisfied link

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface

I am constantly running into error when i try to add .dll to build path of java project.
I have created .dll file with mingw64 using the following command:

```
gcc -o ctest.dll -shared -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\include" 
-I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\include\win32" ctest.c -LC -m64
```

Created .dll file is in the same directory as the main class using the dll.

```
bin/com/jni
```

I have tried to include .ddl to java project from Eclipse by doing the following steps:

- BuildPath -> Native library location -> path_to_directory_with_.dll

This results with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.jni.HelloWorld.helloFromC()V
    at com.jni.HelloWorld.helloFromC(Native Method)
    at com.jni.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)
```

As the above didn't work, i tried to run the application from command line:

```
C:\Users\Z003DP9F\java-8 workspace\workspace\JNI_Test\bin>java 
-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Z003DP9F\java-8 workspace\workspace\JNI_Test\bin\com\jni" 
com.jni.HelloWorld
```

and the same error, although on line 12 rather than 14 like in example above.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.jni.HelloWorld.helloFromC()V
            at com.jni.HelloWorld.helloFromC(Native Method)
            at com.jni.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
```

c file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
{
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

Java main class:

```
package com.jni;

public class HelloWorld {
    native void helloFromC(); /* (1) */
    static {
        
        System.loadLibrary("ctest"); /* (2) */
        
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        helloWorld.helloFromC(); /* (3) */
    }
}
```

The example i have been trying to setup was taken form:

[jni](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature is wrong; you can use **javah** to get the signature for you, but in your case it is simply

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_jni_HelloWorld_helloFromC(JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz)
```